# Authentication in Chromecast CAF Receiver application

Tags: authentication, chromecast

I have a help URL which is to be authenticated with a token before playing it. How can I add a token header to a receiver CAF application? I searched in the documentation but couldn't find any reference of authentication for a receiver CAF application.

In V2 player we can intercept the request with `updateSegmentRequestInfo` as shown below but im not sure how to do it with CAF Application. Can someone help?

```
host.updateSegmentRequestInfo = function(requestInfo) {
            console.log("Inside updateSegmentRequestInfo");
            requestInfo.withCredentials = true;
            requestInfo.headers = {};
            requestInfo.headers['token'] = window.token;
            console.log("token sent");
        };
```

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Answer (score 3):

Set cookies on player load event.

Use this code:

```
const context = cast.framework.CastReceiverContext.getInstance();
const playerManager = context.getPlayerManager();
const castOptions = new cast.framework.CastReceiverOptions();

let playbackConfig = (Object.assign(new cast.framework.PlaybackConfig(), playerManager.getPlaybackConfig()));

playerManager.setMessageInterceptor(
cast.framework.messages.MessageType.LOAD,
request => {

  // Set cookies here. 
  // No need to pass cookies into header in each segment.

  //  console.log("content id:", request.media.contentId);
  //  Set your segment valid hls format : below is example:
  //  Refer other format:
  //  https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/caf_receiver/cast.framework.messages#.HlsSegmentFormat

  request.media.hlsSegmentFormat = cast.framework.messages.HlsSegmentFormat.TS;

  return request;
});

playbackConfig.manifestRequestHandler = requestInfo => {
    requestInfo.withCredentials = true;
};

playbackConfig.segmentRequestHandler = requestInfo => {
    requestInfo.withCredentials = true;
  };

playbackConfig.licenseRequestHandler = requestInfo => {
    requestInfo.withCredentials = true;
};

castOptions.playbackConfig = playbackConfig;
context.start(castOptions);
```

Comment: Thanks Formerly I used "cast.player.api.HlsSegmentFormat.MPEG2_TS" but now I'm using "cast.framework.messages.HlsSegmentFormat.TS". If anybbody googles for that.